# Can I remove "Free space" text from the Nautilus status bar?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, statusbar

I want to remove the part in Nautilus that shows free disk space. In theory it may useful but it's so badly designed, every time I select some files my eye gets drawn to "15 GB" instead of the actual size of the files. And with no files selected, it says something like "24 items, Free space 15GB" which at a quick glance looks like the total size of the files.

I've looked through the preferences and don't see anything. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with Nautilus 2.32.0.

Comment: You should consider filing a bug report, look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs .

Comment: Funny enough when Googling for information I came across this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/389833 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no preference for this change, then unless there's a GConf key for this (which I doubt), you're out of luck unless you want to modify the Nautilus source code yourself and build your own custom Nautilus.

The general approach in Gnome is to ensure that there are as few settings as possible--all in the name of simplicity and usability. This mindset annoys me considerably at times.

Comment: It's a little hypocritical to have fewer settings "in the name of simplicity and usability" when they've also added text that impairs usability...